# render the page using the module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

please tell me why the simplest module at site.ru /userslist brings to the page, and the message
«The requested page" /userslist "could not be found. "

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/k2LAY/)

```
$items['userslist']=array( //userlist - наш url
'title'=>t('Users List'),//Название ссылки
'description'=>t('List of users'),//краткое описание ссылки
'page callback'=>'userslist_form',//вызываемая ф-ция при переходе по ссылке userlist
'access callback' => 'entity_access',
'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
);
return $items;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entity_access` callback expects an `entity_type` as arguments which is missing. Your page is not dedicated for an entity object, I suggest leaving the `access callback` from the menu declaration, which will use the default `user_access` callback.

Don't forget to clear the cache when changing / adding menu item in order your updates are seen by Drupal.

```
$items['userslist']= array( //userlist - наш url
    'title' => t('Users List'),//Название ссылки
    'description' => t('List of users'),//краткое описание ссылки
    'page callback' => 'userslist_form',//вызываемая ф-ция при переходе по ссылке userlist
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
```